# Selenium 2 web driver from the command line

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have done this before but seem to be having a brain freeze and google is not helping

I have selenium 2 web driver in Java with eclipse and I simply want to run a script (class, java) from the command line.

Comment: +1 for admitting you had brain freeze. It's happened to many times, and luckily the fellow posters on this site have been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the classpath, compile the code and then run the code. Something along the lines,

```
set classpath=c:\path\to\my\project\bin\.;c:\path\where\all\required\jars\*;
javac mywebdriver.java
java  mywebdriver
```

I would suggest you to look at [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) for building your code than something like above..